# backgroundworker form closed without cancel async

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I want to know what can be problem if i have the following POC...

```
public void DoProcess() // called as Do_Work
{
    textUpdater = null;
    try
    {
        SetButtonEnabled(false);
        aHandler = new DataHandler();
        aHandler.Initialize(_configuration);
        aHandler.GetDataFromWebAndSave();
        MessageBox.Show("completed");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + " \r\n\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);
    }
    SetButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

Usually a backgroundWorker process includes a loop where one can easily see whether cancel is called or not. In my case, i can't check ...
Say I CLOSE the windows form (containing above code). Will everything be terminated safely ?? 
If not, then how can i do it ?
(i guess other way could be 'use thread').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread proc of your backgroundworker doesn't have to have a loop. And it doesn't have to be cancelled to finish. It simply finishes when... the proc exits!
When it finishes, `RunWorkerCompleted` will be called.

I see a major problem in your call though: You manipulate your GUI from the background thread. This is a no-no! All manipulations of a GUI element must be made from the thread that created the element. In your case, use `ReportProgress()` to delegate status information to the `ProgressChanged` handler that will execute it in the foreground thread.

In addition, as Rewinder wrote, you can cancel the worker from `FormClosing()`. But if you never monitor `CancellationPending` from your worker proc, this is pointless.

Comment: "All manipulations of a GUI element must be made from the thread that created the element." -- can you please explain more ????

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure your backgroundworker is cancelled, you can do something like this:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
     myBackgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
}
```